# Changing default size for already developed winform app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, screen-resolution

i have a tricky one here (i think)

I was just put on a new project where they working on an app which is pretty much done, it is on testing phase. BUT they JUST realized, they developed it on/for 1024*1024 screens, and as it turns out, some of the offices are still running on 800*600 so I have been put in charge of making whatever "quick fixes" is needed for it.

I actually dont use C# much, i just started working with it a month ago. But as far as Ive read, Id have to assign docks AND anchors to all of the controls.
The app runs mainly in 1 form only, that is, a form that has 500+ controls in it, they hide and appear as needed. And a few dozens more are hardcoded, they are created on a fixed point and with a fixed size at runtime.
I already suggested that perhaps it is best to instruct the offices to update their screen resolution (i know they CAN handle 1024*1024, they probably just dont know how or care to it).

So, I guess my question would be, does Visual Studio provides a tool that could help speed up the process of docking/anchoring in the form or does it has to be done manually (as i fear)?

And if it has to be done manually, supposing I have the power to put sense on the right people, should i try to convince them to change the resolutions or is it better to spend whatever time is needed making the app compatible with both resolutions?

Comment: Hacking it to solve the problem isn't a good solution, as you will have to redo all QA work that has previously been done. Unless you get lucky and all coding was done in a resolution-independent way that works down to 800x600.  It is obvious this wasn't done, otherwise they would have caught this issue during the development cycle. Having users update their screen resolution is (like you said) the best solution, and will give them productivity gains anyhow. Also, I don't like this solution, but adding a conditional nag screen to the beginning to fix their resolution might avoid support calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such tool.

And I would forget about anchoring/docking too, because it looks like the layout itself is in code and by changing anchoring/docking you might break something.

So I would quickly tell your supperior, that this will not be quick and easy job.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

Set the form to

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

And then change the font size of the application to a smaller size.

```
this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 6.25F);
```

Hopefully you can get a manageable scale down.